# use angular component function as callback in settings object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback

Question might be easy but I'm quite stuck with it.

I have a `chartjs` options object. There is a callback function within it.

I need to use some component's variable in that function (`this.period`).

Is something like this possible ?

**Component code:**

```
 @Input() period: string;

 public lineChartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    // maintainAspectRatio: false
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          max: 10,
          callback: (function(value, index, values) {
            this.wrapperXAxisCallback(value, index, values)
          })
        }
      }],
    }
  };

  wrapperXAxisCallback(value, index, values) {
    switch (this.period) {
      case '24hr':
        ..... break;
      case 'week':
        ..... break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try switching to an arrow function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use an arrow function so you can access your component `(this)` into the callback function.

```
public lineChartOptions: any = {
responsive: true,
// maintainAspectRatio: false
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      max: 10,
      callback: ((value, index, values) => {
        this.wrapperXAxisCallback(value, index, values)
      })
    }
  }]
}
  };
```

Check the full reference here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @user1935987 who said development has to be hard ? :D

Anyway, if it fix your problem, accept an answer, either mine or Chellapan's one as we said the same thing :)

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
public lineChartOptions: any = {
    responsive: true,
    // maintainAspectRatio: false
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          max: 10,
          callback: ((value, index, values)=>{
            this.wrapperXAxisCallback(value, index, values)
          })
        }
      }],
    }
```